# Find conformal mapping from sector to unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a conformal mapping between the sector $\{z\in\mathbb{C}  : -\pi/4<\arg(z) <\pi/4\}$ and the open unit disc $D$.

I know that it should be a Möbius transformation, but other than that I am very stuck, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Remember that Mobius transformations take circles to circles and lines to lines. Since the boundary of the sector is neither a line nor a circle, Mobius transformations on their own can't possible get you there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a plan: first, apply $z \to z^2$. It will conformally map your sector onto the half-plane $\mathrm{Re}(z) > 0$. Then find a Möbius transformation that will map this half-plane to the unit disk.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even consider composing it with another holomorphic map!

Comment: Why is that conformal? Is not it that f'(0)=0?

Comment: @Ido4848 Sure, $f'(0)=0$, but $0$ does not belong to the given sector, so it's irrelevant. Within the sector $f'(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: Why 0 is not within the sector? Is $Arg(0)=0$?

Comment: The argument of $0$ is undefined.

Answer (score 8):

You know that there is a conformal mapping from the unit disk to the upper half plane given by:
$$z\mapsto -i\frac{z-i}{z+i}$$
Which sends

[image]

to

[image]

But then you know that the transformation $z\mapsto \sqrt z$ taking the principal value sends the upper half plane to the region you are desiring. This gives:

[image]

Reversing these mappings gives:

$$w \mapsto \frac{iw^2+1}{-w^2-i}$$

Which you will see is a conformal mapping sending the first quadrant to the unit disk.