# conformal map of a sector to the right half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I have a sector $S_{\alpha} = \{ z \in \mathbb C \ | \ |arg(z)| \lt \alpha \} $ with $0 \lt \alpha \leq \pi$.

My question is: Does the function $\phi: z \to z^2$ map the sector $S_\alpha$ to the right half plane? And if it does, how exactly? I can't find a solution because if I square $z$ I get $z^2 = z \cdot z = (x+iy)(x+iy) = x^2 - y^2 + i2xy$, where $Re(z) = x^2 - y^2$. And this can be $< 0$

Comment: Are you aware that the function $z \mapsto z^2$ *doubles* the angle of every point?

Comment: @MartinR yes. We have $z = |z| e^{i arg(z)}$. Then it follows that $z^2 = |z|^2 e^{i2arg(z)}$. But this is then $z^2 = |z|^2 \cdot ( \cos(2arg(z)) + i\sin(2arg(z)) )$. $Re(z^2)$ would then be $|z|^2 \cos(2arg(z))$, but this can be $\lt 0$. What Am I missing?

Comment: $z \mapsto z^2$ maps $S_{\pi/4}$ to the right half-plane, but *not* every sector $S_\alpha$.

Comment: @MartinR okay, now I see it.. would then $z^{\frac{\pi}{2\alpha}}$ map $S_\alpha$ to the right half plane? Because $\arg(z) \lt \alpha$, and, If we would allow $\arg(z) = \alpha$, the maximum that we can have would be $ z^{\frac{\pi}{2\alpha}} = |z|^{\frac{\pi}{2\alpha}}  e^{i\frac{\pi arg(z)}{2\alpha}}  = |z|^{\frac{\pi}{2\alpha}} ( \cos(\frac{\pi \alpha}{2\alpha})) + i\sin(\frac{\pi \alpha}{2\alpha}) =  |z|^{\frac{\pi}{2\alpha}} ( \cos(\frac{\pi }{2}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: You should say you have posted a similar question [yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4615150/305862)